# Why is it sufficient to minimize expected prediction error (EPE) pointwise?

Tags: machine-learning

In the elements of statistical learning in section 2.4 it is written that

```
it suffices to minimize EPE (Expected Prediction Error) pointwise.
where
```

EPE = $E_{X} E_{Y/X}([Y-f(X)]^2|X)$

Why minimizing EPE is equivalent to minimizing $E_{Y/X}([Y-f(X)]^2|X)$?
I see that an answer has been posted at [Expected prediction error - derivation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92180/expected-prediction-error-derivation/185235#185235) by Matthew Drury.

Matthew said that you can minimize a sum of non-negative quantities by minimizing the summands individually. But I think that is true only when summands are independent of each other. Are we assuming that in this case.

Comment: Sufficient for what goal?

Comment: for minimizing EPE a whole we need to minimize EPE pointwise.

Comment: That comment is the answer!

Comment: I answered this in detail here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92180/expected-prediction-error-derivation/185235#185235 (I can't vote as a duplicate, because the answer there is not upvoted)

Comment: I have read this answer, I still have one doubt. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @user147798 - if you choose the function $f$ and then condition on the value of $X$ then $f(X)$ is "known".  If, for a particular value of $X=x$, you can make $E[(Y-f(X))^2|X=x]$ smaller then you should redefine $f(x)$ appropriately (as per equation (2.12) in the linked question).

Comment: In more detail: $E[(Y-f(X))^2|X=x] = E[(Y-f(x))^2|X=x] \geq \min_c E[(Y-c)^2|X=x]$.  Thus, you cannot do better than term-wise minimisation.  On the other hand, for every $x$ you can *define* $f(x)=c$, where $c=c(x)$ is a minimiser in $\min_c E[(Y-c)^2|X=x]$, and this attains the term-wise minimum.  N.b. You are choosing a value of $f(x)$ for every $x$, and thus the terms are "independent" in the way I think you mean.

Comment: @P.Windridge-the value of c depends upon how the function $f(X)$ is defined. We want an $f(X)$ such that EPE is minimized. If you minimize EPE for a partcular value of X, it may so happen that overall EPE increases. My doubt is that why there is not any other possible $f(X)$,  which minimizes the EPE.