# Elements of Statistical Learning - Statistical Decision Theory : step 2.10 to 2.11 minimization of EPE

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

Questions about that section of the book (see image below) were already asked and they cover how to get

from 2.9 to 2.11, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92180/expected-prediction-error-derivation/102662#102662)

and from 2.12 to 2.13, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286290/elements-of-statistical-learning-statistical-decision-theory-doubt-regarding)

but do not cover how to get from 2.11 to 2.12!

2.11 can be written as

\begin{align*}
& E_{X}E_{Y|X}([Y - f(X)]^2| X = x) \\
&= \int_x \left( E_{Y|X}([Y - f(X)]^2|X = x) \right) p(x)dx\\
&= \int_x\left( \int_y [y - f(x)]^2p(y|x)dy \right)p(x)dx
\end{align*}

They just say "we see that it is sufficient to minimize EPE point-wise" and drop the integration over x and THEN do a point-wise minimization.

But how come they can just drop the whole $x$ integration? Why is it sufficient to minimize 2.11 it point-wise?

[image]

Comment: You want to minimise $\text{E}_X \text{E}_{Y|X}([Y-f(X)]^2|X)$.  All that $(2.12)$ says is that this happens when  $\text{E}_{Y|X}([Y-f(X)]^2|X)$ is minimised for each $X$ and then $(2.13)$ says this is when $f(x) = \text{E}(Y|X=x)$

Comment: You mean minimized for each x? I get that for one fixed x, $f(x)=E(Y,X=x)$ minimizes 2.11. So you say because the choice for x is arbitrary f minimizes 2.11 in general?

Comment: OK, so $\text{E}_{Y\mid X=x}([Y-f(X)]^2\mid X=x)$ is minimised for that $x$ when $f(x) = \text{E}(Y\mid X=x)$ and so $\text{E}_{X}\text{E}_{Y\mid X}([Y-f(X)]^2\mid X)$ is minimised when $f(X) = \text{E}(Y\mid X)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing on the step of interest:  $E_X\left[E_{Y|X} \left( [Y-f(X)]^2 | X \right) \right]$ can also be written $E_X\left[E_{Y|X} \left( [Y-f(x)]^2 | X=x \right) \right]$.  By conditioning on $X=x$, $f(x)$ becomes a constant with respect to $Y|X$.  At each value of $X$: ${x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots}$, if we can calculate a $f(x_1), f(x_2), f(x_3), \dots$ such that the desired quantity is minimized, then we can eventually determine a point-wise function $f$, or possibly an $f(x)$ that can be expressed analytically as we normally do with a function.

We also recognize that it is sufficient to minimize $g(z)$ if we are minimizing $E_Z(g(Z))$.  There is nothing else that can be changed in the $E_Z()$.  We must integrate over the entire domain, and we take the p.d.f. of $Z$ as a given.

Putting it all together,

$$f: min_f EPE(f) = min_f E_X \left[ E_{Y|X} \left([Y-f(x)]^2|X=x\right) \right]$$

$EPE(f)$ is minimized when $E_{Y|X} \left([Y-f(x)]^2|X=x\right)$ is minimized.

$E_{Y|X} \left([Y-f(x)]^2|X=x\right)$ is minimized at $f(x) = E_{Y|X}(Y|X)$